# How to retrieve a value from an array in a nested JSON-string?

Tags: jquery, json

How do I retrieve the value 90 from the array paramList (in the beginning in `name":"offset","values":["90"]`) in this JSON-string?

```
{"query":{"query":"skole","hits":10,"paramList":[{"name":"hits","values":["10"]},{"name":"offset","values":["90"]},{"name":"q","values":["skole"]}]},"status":"success","facets":[{"selectionType":"AND","numberOfItems":1,"selectableItems":[{"value":"Intranett","displayName":"Intranett","count":146,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&kilde=Intranett"}],"appliedItems":[],"facetName":"Kilde"},{"selectionType":"AND","numberOfItems":4,"selectableItems":[{"value":"EPiServerPage","displayName":"EPiServerPage","count":90,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&type_s=EPiServerPage"},{"value":"Word","displayName":"Word","count":51,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&type_s=Word"},{"value":"ClubNews","displayName":"ClubNews","count":4,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&type_s=ClubNews"},{"value":"Project","displayName":"Project","count":1,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&type_s=Project"}],"appliedItems":[],"facetName":"Type"}],"suggestions":{"displayName":"spellingSuggestion","suggestions":null,"collatedSuggestion":{"suggestion":null,"paramId":"?q=null"}},"errors":[],"numberOfHits":146,"pagination":{"offset":90,"first":{"displayName":"1","selected":false,"end":10,"start":1,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&offset=1"},"next":{"displayName":"11","selected":false,"end":109,"start":100,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&offset=100"},"hitsPerPage":10,"paginationItems":[{"displayName":"5","selected":false,"end":49,"start":40,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&offset=40"},{"displayName":"6","selected":false,"end":59,"start":50,"paramId":"?hits=10&q=skole&offset=50"}, .....
```

In order to retrieve the element query (beginning of the first line) I use `{$T.query.query}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$T.query.query.paramList[1].values[0]` assuming the structure isn't going to change

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`var val = jsonArray["query"]["paramList"][1]["values"];`</strike>

```
var q = jsonArray["query"]["paramList"];

var values = q.map(function(){

    return values[0];

});

var index = values.indexOf(90);
```

Comment: `values` is an array, which is what this expression will evaluate to.

Comment: also, even if this *were* correct, it would return 10, not 90

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Sorry, corrected and updated. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only for that specific value and you know where it will be in the JSON, you can use:

```
var json = 'YOUR JSON STRING HERE';
var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
var value = obj.query.paramList[1].values[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON is evaluated

```
JSON.query.paramList[1].values.[0];
```

return 90.

Comment: Hmmm...this looks an awful lot like my answer. Except my answer has the benefit of being correct.

Comment: Didn't spent much time on that answer and yours poped up after I submitted the answer. But yes there is a second query.